# Is anyone having problems in tailwindcss installed via npm?

Tags: css

I installed tailwind css (the latest version 3.0.0) via npm. But when I input the css file of tailwind and output it in the file I need, the number of components are just a few hundreds whereas it used to be thousands before? I can't even style my elements using colors, fonts... etc.. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Have you tried following the installation instructions? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.